# React.js How to Redirect on submit in a input form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redirect, user-input

I hope your all staying and are well. I'm having trouble redirecting. The project im building makes a api request on a search and displays the images from Flickr to the DOM. I have NavLinks that take the user to pre loaded images from Flickr such as 'Mountains' and loads a route respectively E.G http://localhost:3000/Mountains. When I make another search I would like the route to go back to the home route. Cheers Guys :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../index.css';

export default class SearchBar extends Component {

//setting the state of the search text to empty string.
    state = {
      textInput: '' 
    }
//this function changes the search text state to value sumbited in the input field
    onSearchChange = e => {
      this.setState({ textInput: e.target.value });

    }

//handleSubmit changes stops the default refresh of the page.
//Then it takes the onSearch property set in the SearchBar route
//After search is then complete it is then reset to empty. 
    handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.onSearch(this.query.value);
      e.currentTarget.reset()
    }


//builds out what is to display to the dom.
    render () {
      return (
        <Redirect to="/" />
        <div> 
          <h1>Photo Generator</h1>
          <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
              <input type="search"
                  onChange={this.onSearchChange} 
                  placeholder="Search..." 
                  ref={(input) => this.query = input}                  
                  className="search-form"/>
              <button type="submit" id="submit" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="search-form button">
                  <i className="search-form button:hover"></i>
              </button>
          </form>
        </div> 
      );
    }
  }
```

api call from app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import PhotoList from './Components/PhotoList';
import Nav from './Components/Nav';
import NotFound from './Components/NotFound';
import SearchBar from './Components/SearchBar';
import Waterfall from './Components/Waterfall';
import Sunsets from './Components/Sunsets';
import Mountains from './Components/Mountains';
import './index.css';
import apiKey from './config';

//importing all nesssary components to the app.


//setting the set have to a onject with an empty array on pictures
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pictures: [],
      sunsets: [],
      waterfalls: [],
      mountains: [],
      loading: true
    };
  };

  //componentDidMount calls when everything on the page as been rendered and makes the API request.

  componentDidMount() {
    this.performSearch();
  }

//using axios to automatically take the data from Flickr and convert it JSON.
//It then sets the pictures array in state to the JSON data from Flickr 
// matching the input from the user in the search bar.
//If there is an error with request perfromSearch will catch it.


performSearch = (query = 'Flowers') => {

    axios.get(`API KEY`)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pictures: response.data.photos.photo
      });
    })
      .catch(error => {
      console.log('API request failed', error)
    })

  } 

//rendering all of the routes and paths for the projet.
// <Photo/>  gets passed the data from the API request so that it can be acessed in the photo component.

render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <SearchBar onSearch={this.performSearch} />        
              <Nav />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" />
                    <Route path="/notfound" render={ () => <NotFound /> } />
                    <Route path="/waterfall" render={ () => <Waterfall data={this.state.waterfalls}/> } />
                    <Route path="/sunsets" render={ () => <Sunsets data={this.state.sunsets}/> } />
                    <Route path="/mountains" render={ () => <Mountains data={this.state.mountains} /> } />
                </Switch>
              <PhotoList data={this.state.pictures}/>
          </div>
      </BrowserRouter> 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Randy, first of all you should not use <Redirect /> outside of a <Router>, and then you want the user to be redirected after making the api call right ? if so could you please tell when you are calling the api ?

Comment: Hello Farhani! Cheers bud I will like the code now!

Comment: You can use push method on history object to navigate. props.history.push(URL). you can use hook or withRouter to access history object

Comment: "When I make another search I would like the route to go back to the home route" so here when i am on http://localhost:3000/Mountains and i submit a new search before the user get the new url ex http://localhost:3000/Flowers you want him to be redirected first to the home page http://localhost:3000 and then to the new url right ?